# Как нарисовать 11-ти конечную звезду на turtle? Python

Tags: python, графика, turtle

Нужно нарисовать следующую 11-ти конечную звезду на `turtle`:

[image: Звезда]

Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТ версия-3-8, спасибо, теперь понимаю какую информацию нужно указывать в вопросах

Comment: Помог ответ? Поставьте галочку :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно в лоб замутить:

```
import turtle
import math

# вычислить координаты
radius = 100
center_x = 0
center_y = 0
points_count = 21

points = [(center_x + radius * math.cos(2 * math.pi * i / points_count), center_y + radius * math.sin(2 * math.pi * i / points_count)) for i in range(points_count)]

# построить изображение
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(points[0])
turtle.pendown()

index = 0
while True:
    index += points_count // 2
    index = index % points_count

    turtle.setpos(points[index])

    if index == 0:
        break

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Ничего себе "в лоб"... И это вместо, по сути, одного цикла состоящего из пары команд. :)

Comment: сделайте скидку человеку, знакомство которого с черепахой составило 2 минуты :'(.

Comment: Вот-вот... Хорошо, что ещё какой-нибудь numpy не был задействован, или что-то вроде того. ))

Comment: кстати используя matplotlib суммарно строчки в 3-4 можно было бы уложиться :)

Comment: @Zhihar и без них можно. 2 вариант https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1359135/468004

Answer (score 3):

Помогаю - нужно ехать прямо нужную длину. Потом повернуть на такой угол, чтобы получилась 11 конечная звезда.

Повторить 11 раз

А этот угол - `180-180/11` градусов (черепашка же в градусах работает?)

Answer (score 1):

```
from turtle import *
t = Turtle()
for i in range(11):
    t.right(10)
    t.fd(80)
    t.left(160)
    t.fd(100)
```

Но немного кривенькая. Вот скриншот:

[image: Скриншот]

А лучше ещё так (спасибо @GrAnd):

```
from turtle import *
t = Turtle()
for i in range(11):
    t.right(180-180/11)
    t.fd(200)
```

Вот так получится:

[image: Cкриншот 2]

Comment: Кривая звезда какая-то... :))

Comment: Можно подправить немного величину в `t.right(10)`

Comment: Так всё же проще делается: `from turtle import *
t = Turtle()
for i in range(11):
    t.right(180-180/11)
    t.fd(200)
done()`

Comment: @GrAnd спасибо)